# Trying to replace for loops in R with apply functions for large dataset

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply, replicate

I am trying to perform a simple calculation for a large number of parameter combinations. I have 15,625 permutations, and want to run Monte Carlo experiments (~5000) for each combination. My issue is storing the data properly and avoiding for loops that are taking forever. I'd like to use the apply functions but can't figure them out. I have the following code, which runs, but very inefficiently!  I am interested in saving the "res[i,j]" values.  I've seen that an easy way to do Monte Carlo is using the replicate command...but clearly I'm not there yet....
Any suggestions would be really appreciated!!

```
#run the beta function
beta <- function(M) {
  b_slope <- log(M) / 10
  return (b_slope)
}
#set the experiment conditions for looping through different M, Cv, and q parameter vals
cvVals <- seq(0.1,3.09,0.12)
mVals <- seq(1,2.98,0.08)
qVals <- seq(0.9,0.999,0.004)
mNum <- length(mVals);cvNum <- length(cvVals);qNum<-length(qVals);
total<-mNum*cvNum*qNum

#iterate through time (up to 5000 yrs)
imax<-5000

#Number of experiments
expts<-5

#fill a matrix with each combination of cv, m, q values
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(cv=cvVals, m=mVals, q=qVals))

#set a column in the df to have X_Crit values
df$i<-seq(1:nrow(df))
df$X_crit <- qlnorm(df$q)

#store the results in a df with the dimensions of df by # of experiments
res <- data.frame(nrow=nrow(df), ncol=expts)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  for (j in 1:ncol(res)) {
    #fill in all the x_critical values for each q
    X_crit <- df$X_crit[i]

    #compute the mean and std dev and flow for all values up to imax
    tempmean <- beta(df$m[i])*seq(0, imax-1)
    tempstd <- df$cv[i]*tempmean
    #generate imax random lognorm variables as error terms 
    err <- rlnorm(imax, 0, 1)
    #compute flow from lognormal quantile function
    flow <- tempmean + tempstd*err

    #store the result which looks for the first exceedance of flow 
    if (sum(flow>X_crit)>0) {
      res[i, j] <-min(which(flow > X_crit))
    } else {
      res[i,j] <- imax
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: It appears that you can get rid of the inner loop all together since I see nothing in that loop that depends on `j`, except when you add the values to the data frame.  That last part can be rewritten as `res[i,] <- ...`.  Value recycling will take care of the adding the value to every column.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the for j loop. It seems to be serving no purpose